# Create links to tweet text from entities (hashtags, links, mentions...) of Twitter REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm inserting tweets in one website, but i'm with a little problem to get the entities (hashtags, mentions, links...)

REST Api give us information about the entities, like we can see here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

But, the api give me the indices of this entities in the string text (tweet), but, if i insert a link in this tweet, the other link will change, and make verifications from all cases will spend much time.

Someone know some way to do that, a easy one, or some plugin in jQuery or API that make this for us?

(P.S.: Sorry some error, i'm a brazilian developer and my english was not so good :D )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick google yielded the following gist:

https://gist.github.com/442463

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at this one: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-js